# If text in a specified mentioned username then do not insert for this username

Tags: php, mysql

My mention system need someting. I created the following code for saving mentioned user using php and mysql.

The text is:

```
$text = 'Hi @john ! Need help @stack .';
```

saving Query

```
$mention_regex = '/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/i';
preg_match_all($mention_regex, $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $match) { 
    $match = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $match); 
} 
$mentionTime = time();
$mention_sql = mysqli_query($db,"
INSERT INTO mentions (m_uid_fk, 
m_status, 
m_time ) 
SELECT user_id, '$uid','$mentionTime' 
FROM users 
WHERE user_name IN ('" .implode("','", $matches[1]). "')") 
or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

**My question is:**  If there is a specified user_name in the text like for example `@john` then don't save mentions table for this user_name.

Is there anyway to do this with my query  ?

Comment: Why do tou have 2 query ? Btw the query is invalid

Comment: @executable querys are working fine.

Comment: strpos ... ? also if `$uid` is done via user input .. you're open to SQL injection

Comment: @treyBake Thank you for your attantion for $uid but i will fix SQL injection problem before. What you mean strpos ? Can you explain me please ?

Comment: Is your `user_name` column set as a `UNIQUE KEY` in your database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strpos](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check for certain text within a string:

```
$search = '@john';
$string = 'Hi @john ! Need help @stack .';

if (!strpos($string, $search)) {
    # run save code
}
```

**alternative answer**

use [array_filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) -

```
$users = ['@john', '@trey', '@azzo'];

$data = array_filter($users, function($el)
{
    return ($el !== '@john');
});

echo '<pre>'. print_r($data, 1) .'</pre>';
```

with `array_filter` you can specify your return values using a function that checks the element against a condition. Then just `foreach` that `$data` array and run your code for that only.

e.g.

```
foreach ($data as $item)
{
    # run save code
}
```

Comment: then the query working fine for other @ mentioned usernames right ?

Comment: @Azzo redone conditional - now it'll work for every other user :)

Comment: It is stoped the save query if strpos see `@john` user_name . The query should be continue to work for other mentioned usernames.

Comment: @Azzo shouldn't be - this is only example code - you may have to modify your code but it's basically saying if @ john isn't found do save code - I assume your $search and $string are dynamic?

Comment: The query saving data for every mentioned username like `@john, @trey, @azzo`with uniq id. That is why i am using implode and foreach loop. If use my query between strpos if statement then when strpos see `@john` the query stoped to save other users.

Comment: @Azzo just implode the matches outside the string and use the end result .. I'll add an answer in a sec

Comment: Please don't be mad at me, but I don't know how to use your answer. Can you answer me using the codes I used in my question, please?

Comment: @Azzo not mad :) I'll try and break it down - do you have an array of usernames? e.g. `@john`, `@trey` etc.?

Comment: @Azzo so that's the first line in my code example - it's just the array of user names. Then beneath it we set a new var called $data and use array_filter on our $users array. We pass in a function as the second param to dictate what comes back. In this case we say if $el !== '@john' return that value to the array ]

Comment: sorry Dear i will try to use your answer but it is not clear for me. Please use my question codes in your answer.

Comment: @Azzo my code pretty much does - your $matches var is my $users var - then just add the $data code snippet beneath and you're away :)